# Python selenium not executing bookmarklet properly

Tags: python, selenium, clipboard, bookmarklet

I have a bookmarklet that executes successfully from the browser:

```
javascript:!function(a){var b=document.createElement("textarea"),c=document.getSelection();b.textContent= a,document.body.appendChild(b),c.removeAllRanges(),b.select(),document.execCommand("copy"),c.removeAllRanges(),document.body.removeChild(b);}(<text here>);
```

When I try to execute this through the Selenium webdriver using Python it is returning None. Any thoughts on how to get this to copy the text to the clipboard like the bookmarklet? Full code is below:

```
from selenium import webdriver

chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=chromeOptions, desired_capabilities=chromeOptions.to_capabilities())
driver.implicitly_wait(5)

driver.get("websitehere")

js = """javascript:!function(a){var b=document.createElement("textarea"),c=document.getSelection();b.textContent= a,document.body.appendChild(b),c.removeAllRanges(),b.select(),document.execCommand("copy"),c.removeAllRanges(),document.body.removeChild(b);}(<texthere>);
"""

print(driver.execute_script(js))
```

Comment: did you try without `javascript:`? It is rather only information for browser what to do with rest of string, not JavaScript code. But `execute_script()` may expect only JavaScript code.

Comment: BTW: when I run code I see warning in javascript console - some restriction for `"copy"`. Maybe you have also some message.

Comment: no luck removing `javascript:`

Comment: I am not getting a warning when I run it in the console. It returns true and the text is available on the clipboard.

Comment: don't run in console but using `execute_script()` and after that check what you get in console.

Comment: Tried that and did not see the warning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After some reading online it looks this type of work flow is blocked due to security concerns.  I was seeing this error in the console `chrome document.execCommand(‘cut’/‘copy’) was denied because it was not called from inside a short running user-generated event handler.`

Note that below did not work on Firefox only Chrome may start failing on Chrome in the next couple versions.

```
from selenium import webdriver
import time
import pyperclip
import pyautogui


driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'C:\\Path\\To\\chromedriver.exe')
driver.get("https://www.google.com")
time.sleep(2)
pyautogui.hotkey('ctrl', 'shift', 'j')
time.sleep(2)

js2 = """
var testCopy = function(a) {
var b=document.createElement("textarea"), c=document.getSelection();
b.textContent = a,
document.body.appendChild(b)
c.removeAllRanges()
b.setAttribute("id", "testid")
b.select()
document.execCommand("copy")
console.log('copy success', document.execCommand('copy'));
c.removeAllRanges();
}

testCopy("ThisText")

"""

driver.execute_script(js2)
time.sleep(1)
a = pyperclip.paste()
print(a)
```

Comment: Works great Jortega. Appreciate the help!